# Python-pandas.Dataframe: Dividing columns given by mask-array row-wise by value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**TL;DR**

Consider the following pd.Dataframe:

```
   a0  d2  b3   t4 
0   1   2   3  0.8 
1   3   4   3  9.0 
2   5   6   5  2.5 
3   7   7   7  8.0
```

I want to divide columns specified by a mask `cols = ['a0', 'd2', 'b3']` row-wise (by an element from the row, e.g. `a0`). The following code produces the desired result :

```
# just to surpress pandas chain-assignment warning
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

d = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,.8], [3,4,3,9], [5,6,5,2.5], [7,7,7,8]],columns=["a0", "d2", "b3", "t4"])

# mask
cols = ['a0', 'd2', 'b3']

for i, row in d.iterrows():
    a0 = float(row["a0"])
    for k, v in row.iteritems():
        if k in cols:
            d[k][i] /= a0
```

Output:

```
   a0  d2  b3   t4 
0   1   2   3  0.8 
1   1   1   1  9.0 
2   1   1   1  2.5 
3   1   1   1  8.0
```

**Question**

My question is, if there is a more sophisticated way of performing tthe above code? I am thinking of an expression similar to

```
d.loc[:, cols] /= d.ix[:, ['a0']],
```

which I think almost does the job, but gives me NaN for the divisions:

```
    a0  d2  b3   t4 
0  1.0 NaN NaN  0.8 
1  1.0 NaN NaN  9.0 
2  1.0 NaN NaN  2.5 
3  1.0 NaN NaN  8.0
```

Can anybody give me a hint, on how to correct/replace the last expression, s.t. it works as described (and performs float division)? The solution should be generic enough, to use masks of size ~500, as the column names are not known to me a-priori and I generate them using reg-expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
d[cols] = d[cols].div(d['a0'], axis = 0).astype('int')

out:

a0  d2  b3  t4
0   1   2   3   0.8
1   1   1   1   9.0
2   1   1   1   2.5
3   1   1   1   8.0
```

Comment: With .astype(float), it works like a charm, thank you!